# when we are inheriting a class and interface then we have to write first extends and then implements but not viceversa?why

Tags: java

why in inheritance first we have to write first extends and then inheritance why not implements and then extends ?what makes then to think in this angle

```
class A{}
interface B{}
```

if we write

```
class C implements B extends A {}
```

it will show compile time error but if we write

```
class c extends A implements B{}
```

it will run fine  why so?

Answer (score 3):

Because it is defined that way in the [Language Specification #8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1):

> NormalClassDeclaration:
>           ClassModifiers<sub>opt</sub> class Identifier TypeParameters<sub>opt</sub> Super<sub>opt</sub> Interfaces<sub>opt</sub> ClassBody

As you can see, the extending part (Super<sub>opt</sub>) comes before the implementing part (Interfaces<sub>opt</sub>).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just a simple demand of the Java language.
For example you cannot write int private variable, the access modifiers and data types have to be at a special position. The same here with the inheritance (class Y extends Z implements A).

Comment: if it is syntax then how we are  achieving  it using interface the same way we can do by using class also but it is not allowing?

Comment: You cannot achieve that. There must be any difference between interfaces and classes in Java. Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so there are interfaces to "replace" that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it's a design decision, defined in the Java Language Specification. It doesn't explain *why* the order has to be strict, but Java has strict rules by design (and that's one of the qualities that helps to keep many cryptic bugs away).

A possible reason is that `extends` represents a a stronger relationship than `implements` (although both represent "is a" or "is a type of" relationships). If a certain class implements dozens of interfaces, and it were allowed to list the interfaces before the class, you might miss the important `extends` clause which scroll off the screen.

Being strict also makes writing the compiler easier than if the rules were lax. Since only one `extends` class is allowed, as soon as you read the `extends` token and the class name you are done and can read the next tokens. If you could use `implements` before `extends`, then you would have to parse a list of interfaces before the `extends`.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense:

- You can extend a class, using an `extend` keyword, to produce a bigger class (base + extension)
- You can extend an interface, using an `extend` keyword, to produce a bigger interface (base + extension).

It is the same mechanism, thus the same name. It is some form of a programmatic "copy and paste" - as I always liked to think of it: we copy the source from base class and paste into the other one. We can also copy some text from base interface to another one (the extended).

Now, we need the distinction between a class and an interface and it's a pratical one: interface describes a contract, class follows some contract.

So there is a relation between a class and interface: the `class` fullfills a contract (`interface`). Another words, `class` `implements` an `interface`.

As for your example:
`class c extends A implements B{}` can be deconstructed into:

- class c extends    A
- class c implements B

A class can only extend another class.
A class can only implement an interface.

As for the first example
`class C implements B extends A {}` - it cannot be deconstructed and the reason is only based on the grammar! Purely on syntactical (textual) level it's forbidden.

Comment: my question is why multiple inheritance is not by class  but can be possible using interface?

Comment: Ah, that's a Gosling's decision. One of the reasons he provided is to avoid the so called 'diamond problem': the interface has no fields and thus the problem doesn't exist. The other reason could be that the class is a focused unit. The single responsibility principle states that class should do one thing only. Multiple inheritance is highly correlated with probability of multiple responsibilities.